# How to get second-order equation from 2 first-order equations with the same dependent variable?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, measurements, statistics

I have a current sensor thats returns an output in voltage (Ts) dependent on the current that passes throught the inputs (I) and the voltage feed input (Ta).
I built a table and measured the Ts, while changing the I and Ta:

[image]

In microsoft excel I can retrieve the linear equation to each column or line at a time like Ts=m*I+b for Ta constant and Ts=m*Ta+b for I constant but I wanted the equation that relates all 3 like Ts=a*I+b*Ta+c.

How can I do that?

Comment: There isn't much physics here. You might want to ask this on [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well yeah, basically i'm looking for a mathematical solution for a physics problem. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

The type of analysis you need is called multiple linear regression, and Excel does do this though you need an add-on called the Analysis Toolpak.

I'm not sure it is appropriate to go into the detail of how to do this in Excel, partly because that is really more suited to sites like [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) that specialise in statistical analysis, and partly because a quick Google will find you many articles on [how to do multiple linear regression in Excel](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excel%20multiple%20linear%20regression).

For what it's worth I ran your figures through Excel and got:

```
a   0.01958
b   0.48134
c   0.06192
```

where:

$$ T_s= aI + bT_a + c $$